# How to translate a set of PSTricks objects and rotate it?

Tags: pstricks

To illustrate the problem, consider a simple example with which you are familiar: A mechanical system that consists of a block lying on an inclined plane.

I attached a Cartesian coordinate system to the block and also displayed the weight vector.
I want to draw the system easily with minimal calculation and the simplest workflow.

**The first step:** I draw each part separately as follows:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\def\block{%
    \psaxes[ticks=none,labels=none,linestyle=dashed]{->}(0,0)(-2,-2)(2,2)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \psframe*[linecolor=gray,opacity=0.5](-1,-0.5)(1,0.5)
    \psdots[linecolor=red](0,-0.5)
    \psline{->}(1.5;-45)
    \uput[-45]{45}(1.5;-45){$\vec{w}$}  
}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=bottom](-3,-9)(6,2)
    \block
    \pspolygon(-1,-2)(5,-8)(-1,-2|5,-8)
    \psdots[linecolor=blue](1,-4)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

**The next step:** I attempted to merge them as follows:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\def\block{%
    \psaxes[ticks=none,labels=none,linestyle=dashed]{->}(0,0)(-2,-2)(2,2)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \psframe*[linecolor=gray,opacity=0.5](-1,-0.5)(1,0.5)
    \psdots[linecolor=red](0,-0.5)
    \psline{->}(1.5;-45)
    \uput[-45]{45}(1.5;-45){$\vec{w}$}  
}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=bottom](-3,-9)(6,2)
    \rput{-45}(1,-4){\block}
    \pspolygon(-1,-2)(5,-8)(-1,-2|5,-8)
    \psdots[linecolor=blue](1,-4)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Do you see the weird part? Half of the block was submerged into the inclined plane. I want to fix it.

**The general question is:**
How to translate a system of PSTricks objects such that a certain point (belongs to the system) is coincident with a destination point and rotate the system about the certain point?

Note: If you have another tricky idea but simpler, please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code uses the rotation by `\psrotate` In this way you can specify the rotation point.

[image]

```
% !TEX program = arara
% !TEX encoding = utf8
% !TEX spellcheck = en_GB
%: Start Header
% arara: latex: {synctex: true}
% arara: dvips
% arara: ps2pdf

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\def\block{%
    \psaxes[ticks=none,labels=none,linestyle=dashed]{->}(0,0)(-2,-2)(2,2)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \psframe*[linecolor=gray,opacity=0.5](-1,-0.5)(1,0.5)
    \psdots[linecolor=red](0,-0.5)
    \psline{->}(1.5;-45)
    \uput[-45]{45}(1.5;-45){$\vec{w}$}  
}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=bottom](-3,-9)(6,2)
 \rput(1,-3.5){\psrotate(0,-.5){-45}{\block}}
 \pspolygon(-1,-2)(5,-8)(-1,-2|5,-8)
  \psdots[linecolor=blue](1,-4)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The same should hold for `\rput[<refpoint>]{<angle>}(x,y){<stuff>}`.

Comment: @Werner: I tried: `\rput[0,-.5]{-45}(1,-3.5){\block}` but it fails

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: `<refpoint>` should be `t`, `b`, `l`, `r` or similar, rather than a coordinate. Tried is as well and it didn't work. Don't know why...?

Comment: @Forgiver: I've added an answer the differs slightly from @_MarcoDaniel's; using `\rput` inside `\rput` to adjust vertically before placement.

Answer (score 5):

Adding an extra vertical adjustment inside the existing `\rput` takes care of the proper baseline alignment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pstricks-add

\def\block{%
  \psaxes[ticks=none,labels=none,linestyle=dashed]{->}(0,0)(-2,-2)(2,2)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
  \psframe*[linecolor=gray,opacity=0.5](-1,-0.5)(1,0.5)
  \psdots[linecolor=red](0,0)
  \psline{->}(1.5;-45)
  \uput[-45]{45}(1.5;-45){$\vec{w}$}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=bottom](-3,-9)(6,2)
  \rput{-45}(1,-4){\rput{0}(0,0.5){\block}}% Modified code
  \pspolygon(-1,-2)(5,-8)(-1,-2|5,-8)
  \psdots[linecolor=blue](1,-4)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Even though I accepted Marco's answer, I used your answer in the production. Yours is simpler than Marco's.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pstricks-add

\def\block{%
  \psaxes[ticks=none,labels=none,linestyle=dashed,linecolor=red]{->}(0,0)(-2,-2)(2,2)[$x$,90][$y$,90]%
  \psframe*[linecolor=gray,opacity=0.5](-1,-0.5)(1,0.5)%
    \rput{*0}(0,0){\psline[linecolor=blue]{->}(0,-1.2)\uput[-90](0,-1.2){$\vec{w}$}}%
}
\begin{document}
\multido{\n=.0+.1}{11}{%
\begin{pspicture}[dimen=m](-1,-1)(8,9)
  \pspolygon(0,7)(0,0)(6,0)
    \pcline[linestyle=none,offset=0](0,7)(6,0)\naput[labelsep=-\pslinewidth,nrot=:U,npos=\n]{\rput(0,.5){\block}}
\end{pspicture}}

\end{document}
```

[image]